# Records getting dropped in GCP Spanner due to high CPU utilization of high priority transactions

Tags: python, google-cloud-spanner

We are trying to insert 1 Million rows data in spanner tables using transaction mode using multi-threading and multiprocessing to utilize Spanner to its maximum.

We have used 20 Processes to run in parallel and each process has Thread-pool with `max_workers = 20` and also dynamically increasing the number of nodes.
But when CPU utilization is greater than 80% than records are getting dropped.

`run_in_transaction` function is being used to insert data in transaction mode.

Did anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Spanner performance is highly dependent on workload, schema design and dataset characteristics [1].

Dataset size can be a contributing factor to CPU over usage as the computational overhead for reads and writes grows in parallel with your dataset. Therefore optimizing your schema to coping with the workload is recommended.

If there are back-ups running while rows are being inserted, disable them temporarily and re-run the write.

You can set up notifications on Stack Monitoring to send alerts when your CPU utilization reaches a defined threshold. The recommended threshold to maintaining CPU optimization is 65 percent [2]. When the usage reaches that level , add more nodes to sustain the request rate. Once the CPU usage is down, remove the nodes and see if requests are still dropping.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design
[2] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/instances